# How can I prevent animations from running again on page reload?

Tags: reactjs, css-animations, styled-components

I have  a React.js app where I have an html element called platform. This element has animations attached to itself in css and the animations change based on the state of this element. When I change the element state an animation triggers and this is a desired effect but then once the animation is over, I go to another page, come back and the animation starts again even though I did not trigger it. How can I prevent that from happening? How can I make it so that an animation happens only when state has been changed but if I go to another page and come back, then it does no happen?

I have the following html element:

```
const Platform = styled.img`
  width: 45px;
  height: 60px;
  z-index: 1;
  opacity: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 193px;
  left: 135px;
  transition: transform ${(props)=> props.platformAnimationDuration}s; //7.9s 
  transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform-origin: 44% 72%;  

  ${(props) => props.neutralState != null && props.neutralState === "deployingPlatform" && props.activeMode === "neutral"
    && css`
      animation: ${rotateToNegative119deg} ${props.platformAnimationDuration - 3}s linear forwards;
  `}


  ${(props) => props.neutralState != null && props.neutralState === "platform" && props.activeMode === "neutral"
  && css`
    transform: rotate(-119deg);
  `}

  ${(props) => props.neutralState != null && props.neutralState === "retractingPlatform" && props.activeMode === "neutral"
  && css`
    animation: ${rotateTo0deg} ${props.platformAnimationDuration - 3}s linear backwards;
  `}

  ${(props) => props.neutralState != null && props.neutralState === "neutral" && props.activeMode === "neutral"
    && css`
      transform: rotate(0deg);
  `}

`;
```

I store the state of the element in a useContext which I call in my component where the element is:

```
  const [platformServerState, setPlatformServerState] = useState(null);
```

I have also added in the useContext a state to keep track of whether the animation has been played hoping to use that to prevent the undesired effect explained above.

```
  const [platformAnimationHasPlayed, setPlatformAnimationHasPlayed] = useState(false);
```

This is what I do to change the platform state:

```
async function MovePlatform(newState) {
  const direction = newState === deployedPlatformState ? 'Down' : 'Up';
  
  try {      

    if (newState === deployedPlatformState) {
      setPreviousModesStates((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        neutralState: modeStates.neutralState
      }))

      setModeStates((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        neutralState: deployedPlatformState,
      }));
    }
    else if(modeStates.neutralState === deployedPlatformState && newState === neutralState) {
      setPreviousModesStates((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        neutralState: modeStates.neutralState
      }))

      setModeStates((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        neutralState: retractingPlatformState,
      }));
    }
}
```

And here are my useEffects, that synch the server state with the local state:

```
 useEffect(()=> {
    if (platformServerState !== null && platformServerState !== undefined) {
      console.log("PLATFORM: ", platformServerState);
      setModeStates((prevState) => ({
        ...prevState,
        neutralState: platformServerState,
      }));
      setIsLoading(false);
      console.log("On first start platformServerState, ", platformServerState);
    }
  }, [])


  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Platform Updating ", modeStates.neutralState)
    
    if(platformServerState != null) {
        setModeStates((prevState) => ({
            ...prevState,
            neutralState: platformServerState,
        }));

    }
  }, [modeStates.neutralState, platformServerState, setModeStates]);
```

I am not quite sure how to use my animationHasPlayed state in this logic. I tried setting it in the useEffect but that stopped my animation from working at all.